# How to properly string replace in Powershell without appending the replaced variable to a newline?

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to powershell/programming so bear with me. I have this bug that appends the new renamed path to a new-line without the rest of path. 
The console output:

```
/content/pizza/en/ingredients/
helloworld/menu-eng.html
```

What I want:

```
/content/pizza/en/ingredients/helloworld/menu-eng.html
```

What the code below is supposed to do is rename a bunch paths. Right now testName is hard-coded but after I get this to work properly it will be dynamic.

My code:

```
$testName = "helloworld"
$text = (Get-Content W:\test\Rename\rename.csv) | Out-String
$listOfUri = Import-Csv W:\test\Rename\rename.csv

foreach ($element in $listOfUri) {
    if ($element -match "menu-eng.html") {    
        $elementString = $element.'ColumnTitle' | Out-String
        $elementString = $elementString.Replace('menu-eng.html', '')
        $varPath1 = $elementString

        $elementString = $elementString.Insert('', 'http://www.pizza.com')
        $elementName = ([System.Uri]$elementString).Segments[-1]
        $elementString = $elementString.Replace($elementName, '')
        $elementString = $elementString.Replace('http://www.pizza.com', '')
        $varPath2 = $elementString.Insert($elementString.Length, $testName + '/')

        $text = $text.Replace($varPath1.Trim(), $varPath2)
    }
}
$text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `.csv` file looks like this:

```
ColumnTitle,Idk
/content/pizza/en/ingredients/SPAM/menu-eng.html,Stuff
```

Then:

```
$testName = 'helloworld'
foreach ($row in Import-CSV d:\rename.csv) {
    $bit = $row.'ColumnTitle'.Split('/')[-2]
    $row.'ColumnTitle'.replace($bit, $testName)
}
```

I have no real idea what all the rest of your code is for, particularly my earlier comment, your line:

```
$text = (Get-Content W:\test\Rename\rename.csv) | Out-String
```

is making `$text` into an `/array/` of all the lines in the file, including the headers. You can still use `.Replace()` on it in PowerShell, but it's going to do the replace on every line. I can't quite see how that gives you the output you get, but it will give you multiple lines for every line in the input file.

Comment: My money is definitely on `Out-String` as the culprit here

Comment: You were right, it was the second Out-String causing the problem. If anyone wants to explain why it happened I would love to hear it. Thanks again both of you.